# Negative lookbehind to get latest occurence of text before match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the following text, I would like to match only the bold part:

> hello world fixedText blah blah foo bar **fixedText bar foo blah bar search=123**

I currently have this regex:

> fixedText(.+?)search=(\d+)

which returns the following string

> fixedText blah blah foo bar fixedText bar foo blah bar search=123

My understanding is that I need a negative lookbehind to take away the first "*fixedText blah blah foo bar*" part.
I've tried lots of different combinations with ?=, ?<=, ?!, etc... in different places (yes I even went randomly) without success.

This regex made sense to me, because to my understanding it's saying: "make sure there are no other "fixedText" before the one you're matching", but what happens is that it selects from the very beginning of the string:

> (?<!fixedText)(.+?)search=(\d+)

So basically I'm clueless.
Thanks!

Comment: [`fixedText((?:(?!fixedText).)+?)search=(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EfPGYN/1)

Comment: Will the text you want to match always be at the end of the string?

Comment: Another common trick: `.*(fixedText(.+?)search=(\d+))`, https://regex101.com/r/lWTZBD/1.